# BeautifulSoup error in Python's Mechanize

Tags: python, macos, beautifulsoup, mechanize

I installed BeautifulSoup on my Mac using `easy_install` with no errors, And I can run the test.py file perfectly with no errors also. But when I try to use BeautifulSoup in another file, I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Conor/Desktop/test.py", line 54, in <module>
    from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
ImportError: No module named BeautifulSoup
```

All I have on line 54 is `from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup` And it gives me an error

What is going on here? How can I fix this?

**NOTE: test.py contains:**

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
a = "<a>foo" * 10000
soup = BeautifulSoup(a)
soup.findAll("a")
soup.findAll("a", recursive=False)
print soup
```

**EDIT:**

OK I have been working away at this. Turns out if I move my test.py file INTO the folder where BeautifulSoup is located (/Documents/mechanize-0.2.5/BeautifulSoup/) it runs perfectly. Outside this folder, none of the files work. What the **** is going one here?!?!? And how do I fix it?

Comment: Are the two files in the same location?

Comment: Nope one in the desktop one in the documents folder

Comment: OK I have been working away at this. Turns out if I move my test.py file INTO the folder where BeautifulSoup is located (/Documents/mechanize-0.2.5/BeautifulSoup/) it runs perfectly. Outside this folder, none of the files work. What the **** is going one here?!?!? And how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you install using `sudo`?  It's odd that any `easy_install` module would end up in `/Documents`.  (And it's odd that you have a `Documents` directory below the `/Users` level.)

On OS X (10.7.1) and I installed and used `BeautifulSoup` with no errors.

```
$ sudo pip install BeautifulSoup
$ python
>>>import BeautifulSoup
>>>BeautifulSoup.__file__
'/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/BeautifulSoup.pyc'
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like python doesn't know about the beautiful soup module.
You should be able to import BS from any python script regardless of its location.

Not sure if this would work but you could try manually installing BS by changing to the beautiful soup directory and

```
python BeautifulSoup-x.py install
```

Where x is the version you are using.